# Finding vertices with a given degree; or, finding indices

Tags: graphs-and-networks, filtering

I have a graph `g` and would like to find all the vertices in `g` with degree `n`.

`VertexDegree[g]` gives a list of the degrees, and

```
# == n & /@ VertexDegree[g]
```

gives a list of `True`/`False` for each vertex, but I don't know how to get the indices. That is, I want

> {1, 3}

rather than

> {True, False, True, False, False, False}

Comment: You could use `Position[]` on the result of `VertexDegree[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get vertex names:

```
Pick[VertexList[g], VertexDegree[g], n]
```

Get vertex indices:

```
Pick[Range@VertexCount[g], VertexDegree[g], n]
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by JM in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115755/finding-vertices-with-a-given-degree-or-finding-indices/115756#comment314217_115755), here's how you would find the vertex index of vertices of degree 5 in the following graph:

```
g = GraphData[{"Fan", {4, 4}}];
VertexDegree[g]                              (* {5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4} *)
Flatten@Position[VertexDegree[g], 5]         (* {1, 4} *)
```

The `Flatten` is there to provide the output format you indicated, since `Position` will produce a nested list otherwise.